# android rooted phone and apps

Tags: android, sqlite, google-play, rooted-device

I want to have a large database on an android app. The database is a self contained file that might have 2-3 updates per month (each 20mb+ but I predict that the maximum should be around 40mb).

I keep hearing that the android apps get rooted so people can access those sensitive data (it's going to be a paid app). How can I encrypt the data of the database so that there will be no loss. Is there any alternative database (except from sqlcypher) model (even key/value) that can be used and is more secure?

Also, can a rooted phone user buy an android app from external store (I am thinking on making an external non android market store, due to subscription limitations) and has full access to its contents?

I want to do something similar of the iphone model, where there is no apparent access to the database (if you don't put it to the Documents or enable your device for sharing).

Answer (score 1):

If you use H2 you can encrypt the tables of the database.

So only your application can mount and access it.

You should of course not store the key in a single String though, as this would be easy to find out with a decompile, even after obfuscation.

In general however you should ask yourself if this is really a good model.

Comment: I am to the opinion that you should use web services (request/response), but the one who wants the app requires to be able to read offline every bit of the database, and occasionally have updates (it's encyclopedia content). 

Is there anything else to use as a data model (readonly, updating, offline)? I am fairly new at this.

Comment: Also, thanks for the H2 tip, I see that unicode is not supported fully to android sqlite (as said to another so post) and I really need unicode support on this.

Answer (score 1):

"The iPhone model" is defeated by jailbreaking just as easily.

If both the database and the code that works with it are on a rooted phone, a determined enough attacker will get to the data eventually. A debugger and a breakpoint at just the right moment is all they need. Also, Java code is notoriously easy to reverse engineer. Since you have to ship the decryption code to the user (otherwise, how will the app work?), the same user can isolate and leverage your own decryption code.

Comment: I understand that jailbreaking the iphone can do those things as rooting the phone, I "believe" in app store distribution for now.